# How to add functionality or data to Sitecore Launchpad

Tags: sitecore-client, speak, launchpad

How do I add new data to the Sitecore Launchpad similar to the graphs below the launchpad tiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is to create a rendering in the Core database and add it to the Launchpad application's presentation details using Sitecore Rocks.

**Note: this has only been tested on Sitecore 8.1 update-3, though it's likely to work with other versions.**

## Add a rendering in the Core database

1. In the core database, add a new controller rendering below `/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Renderings` (template is at `/System/Layouts/Controller rendering`)
2. Fill in the necessary fields for your rendering (**Controller**, **Controller Action**, **Area**, etc.)

## Update Launchpad to include your new rendering

1. In [Sitecore Rocks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JakobChristensen.SitecoreRocks)' Sitecore Explorer, open the Core database and right-click on the `/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad` item
2. Select **Tasks** -> **Design Layout** from the context menu

   > Note: At this point, you need to decide where on the Launchpad you would like to add the component. I decided to put mine to the right of the main dashboard of tiles (LaunchTiles).
3. Select **ColumnPanel1**, find the **GridColumns** property, and change it to **9**
4. Select the **LaunchTiles** rendering below **ColumnPanel1** and click the **Add Rendering** button in the top left corner of the tab

   [image: add rendering button]
5. In the resultant dialog, find and select the **ColumnPanel** rendering and click **OK**
6. After you ensure that your new rendering (**ColumnPanel2**) is selected, find the **PlaceholderKey** property and change its value to **RowPanel1.Content**
7. Click the **Add Rendering** button again, this time finding and selecting your new rendering and clicking **OK**
8. After you ensure that your custom rendering is selected, update its **PlaceholderKey** property value to **ColumnPanel2.Content**
9. Click Save

For the full details and an example rendering, [check out the blog post](https://horizontalintegration.blog/2018/12/26/add-custom-widget-to-sitecores-launchpad/).